# Does resetting NVRAM reset EFI Boot Order?

Tags: startup, dual-boot, efi, nvram

I've had a Macbook Pro for a year or so now and have experimented with quite a few Linux distributions which have added and changed things in the EFI Boot Order. I am looking to clean things up. The tool `efibootmgr` for Linux does let me make changes and cleanup as necessary. However will resetting NVRAM reset the EFI Boot Order for me?

Comment: AFIK only OSX system reinstall does that.

Answer (score 0):

NVRAM is a standalone chip on your logic board, backed up by small battery.

EFI resides on your SSD. (hard drive)

Showing battery for the PRAM (NVRAM)

[image]

So no, resetting NVRAM will not impact EFI.

To restore EFI, you have to reinstall the OS X.

Comment: I'm pretty sure "Which OS should I boot by default" is at least sometimes stored in an NVRAM variable. In Hackintosh systems, if emulated nvram isn't working properly, changing the startup disk won't work.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy you mean from which disk not which OS

Comment: Well, this applies to different partitions on the same disk as well.

Comment: I have experienced that resetting the PRAM may have the effect of making Linux boot possible.  The fact that NVRAM and EFI storages are separate is good to know but does not allow to conclude, as some program could read in NVRAM and write in EFI.  Moreover the linux program `efibootmgr` seems to be able to act on EFI without reinsalling OSX (I did not try).

Answer (score 0):

I am not a specialist but I think the answer is yes.

[On system which uses the UEFI firmware, EFI boot manager entries are stored in the non-volatile RAM.](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-manage-efi-boot-manager-entries-on-linux#:%7E:text=Machines%20with%20support%20for%20the,by%20using%20the%20efibootmgr%20utility.)

So it seems that if you reset the NVRAM (alias PRAM) then boot order might be affected.

Indeed I have just checked that resetting the PRAM on my Macbook wiped the output of `efibootmgr`.

Installing MacOX X is not necessary to restore the EFI partition, installing any Linux will do it also. (Mac OS also installs a recovery partition.)